# How to set Image fit on every devices in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel

I am a beginner in Flutter and I just making a simple image carousel application using carosel_slider package. What I want is an image should look on all devices. Image width should be greater than height. The emulator shows fine, but not on my device. I have read [this post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a), but still, I don't know how to do it.

```
 AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      "https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*ZMOh7JwiTAVVHF8e7sijNg.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **

> MediaQuery.of (context).size

**, you can get the size of the phone. The event you want to describe in the medium article is proportional by taking the page size instead of giving it a fixed height. this is the most logical thing anyway. But in the case of the image sometimes it may not eat. So you may need to use extra fix atribute.

```
 Container(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      image: DecorationImage(
       image: NetworkImage(
          "https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*ZMOh7JwiTAVVHF8e7sijNg.png"),
       fit: BoxFit.cover,
     ),
   ),
```